# sed: How to insert before and after every line?

Tags: regex, sed, posix

I'm trying to figure out how to insert text *before* and *after* every line in a text file using `sed` on OS X, but something is obviously wrong with my approach.

This is what I have:

```
sed 's/\(^\).\($\)/A \1\2 Z/g' input
```

This is what I want:

**input:**

```
bbb

ccc
ddd
```

**output:**

```
A bbb Z

A ccc Z
A ddd Z
```

**EDIT:** Also, don't match blank lines (or those containing only spaces).

Comment: `s/(.+)\n/A \1 Z\n/g` this will match an entire line and prepend `A` and append `Z`

Comment: `sed 's/^/A /;s/$/ Z/'` or `sed 's/.*/A & Z/'`

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable I get `sed: 1: "s/(.+)\n/A \1 Z\n/g": \1 not defined in the RE` @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９Much better.

Comment: @octosquidopus ow, sorry. i think it should be `$1` instead

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable No it shouldn't, you need to escape the `+` and brackets. Also don't include `\n`'s as it won't match the first part.

Comment: GNU `sed` behaves somewhat differently from other versions of `sed` w.r.t whether you need to use `\(` or `(` to start captures, etc.  It is partly controlled by the `-r` option — that definitively enables some simpler syntax; there may also be some 'intuition' (heuristics?) employed by GNU `sed` about which notation you want.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Pretty sure you can use ERE in all sed's now can't you? It's just posix ones use `-E` instead of `-r`.

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９:  Most versions of `sed` don't recognize ERE notation unless the option is specified.  GNU `sed` sometimes appears to recognize the ERE-ish (and even some PCRE-ish) notations even without being told to do so.  I've not worked whether that's me being silly or GNU `sed` being clever.  It complicates life because `sed` doesn't behave the same everywhere.  (I also have to work on a platform where `grep` doesn't support `-r` (recursive) search — I was surprised to find recently, after several years away from it.  Its `sed` won't have ERE support.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ah right. I've only ever seen it use ERE when a flag is used. Have to keep my eye out for that!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to insert a line using sed before a pattern and after a line number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284518/how-to-insert-a-line-using-sed-before-a-pattern-and-after-a-line-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed 's/.*/A & Z/' file
A bbb Z
A ccc Z
A ddd Z
```

`&` is back-reference of complete match in regex pattern.

Or using awk:

```
awk '{print "A", $0, "Z"}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
sed 's/.*/A \0 Z/' input
```

- **.*** will match the full line
- **\0** will past the full thing from the first expression

Comment: The use of `\0` is intriguing.  I've not seen that before (I use `&` for the same job), but it seems to work OK with Mac OS X (BSD) `sed` — effectively as a synonym for `&`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's fine to use `\0`, just no one does as `&` does the same.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I am on OSX and `\0` doesn't work, I just get `0` in output. I don't think it is portable. (It worked with gnu-sed though).

Comment: @anubhava: Curious. _[…time passes…]_  Oh, I'm using GNU `sed` after all; it just wasn't in the directory I thought it was installed in (newer machine, I've chosen to try a different convention for where non-Apple s/w is installed).  Please note that my previous comment applies to GNU `sed`; Mac OS X `sed` does not interpret `\0` as equivalent to `&`.  This amply justifies my other comments about GNU `sed` not behaving the same as other variants of `sed`.

Comment: I've learnt something as well :-) I've never used `&` before. But I could not find any ref for the `\0` in any `sed`-related pages. But I found it on the vim-regep page http://vimregex.com/#backreferences and that is where my regexp knowledge springs...