# Write into a certain line number of a file using a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In a shell script, I get the certain number of a line in a file and store it in a variable using the code below:

```
res=$(grep -n '123' somefile.txt | sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\):.*$/\1/')
```

Now I want to write in 3 lines after this line, so I used these codes :

```
sed -i '$res\anything' somefile.txt
sed -i '$resianything' somefile.txt
```

but they don't work.  It seems that `sed` doesn't accept variables.
How can I solve it? Is there any alternative way?

Answer (score 1):

Some tips before pointing out the [duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284518/how-to-insert-a-line-using-sed-before-a-pattern-and-after-a-line-number):

- Variables won't be expanded within [single quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).
- Variable name boundaries are not detected automatically. `$resianything` will not expand to the value of the variable `res` followed by the string `ianything`, but rather to the value of the variable with the name `resianything`, which presumably is empty. You can detect this kind of error by adding `set -o nounset` (and ideally `-o errexit`) at the top of your script.
- You'll definitely want to [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2705678/96588) the string you're inserting back into a `sed` command.

Comment: But writing `${res}ianything` would work as long as variables are expanded, …

Comment: Sure; all that is explained at the quotes link. This probably isn't the right place for a complete introduction to Bash.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking why the `$res` isn't expanding. That isn't a `sed` issue; it's the shell.  Typically bash &c. don't expand variables within single quotes.  Try double quoting that bit.

Also, one method for separating your variable from following alphanumeric text is to use curly braces.  Try `${res}anything` instead of `$resanything`, for example.

Comment: hi, thanks. i used >> sed -i  ${res}ianything somefile.txt and it worked. without i, at the end of ${res}i it didn't write the "a" at the first of anything